# JQuery .load () in a loop does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to run the following code, but it works either way I need to:

```
if(my_condition){
    $('body').append("<div id='loaddiv'><div>");
    for(var i=1; i<=100; i++){
        var dl = 0;
        $('#loaddiv').load('/script/?p='+i);
        dl = $('#loaddiv .standart-view tr').length;
        alert(dl);
    }
}
```

Thus, I have to get the number of tr-elements, which is the parent element with class standart-view, and his parents - div block c id = load214235, for each page, but constantly displays zeros in the Alert :( I tried to upgrade the code, adding all the code in the load-callback function, but still does not work ...

```
if(my_condition){
    $('body').append("<div id='loaddiv'><div>");
    for(var i=1; i<=100; i++){
        var dl = 0;
        $('#loaddiv').load('/folder/?p='+i, function(){
            dl = $('#loaddiv .standart-view tr').length;
            alert(dl);
        });
    }
}
```

+I have yet to load after going condition with break; firebug it just swears that break does not know that close ... How do I get out of the situation? I feel that something with a visibility of variables and data do not have time to load another page, and the script is running on. Jquery is connected, the rest of the code is working, including the functions of jquery, the hierarchy of elements on another page observed (number of tr should be).

Comment: Makes no sense.... load would keep overwriting the content...

Comment: I know! I need to find a solution to this problem.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I am being loaded every page in a loop in DIV and trying to count the number of tr elements using Alert (it displays the result)

Answer (score 0):

First load is an Asynchronous call, you are treating it as synchronous. You are reading the content before the Ajax call is returned. Hence why it is always zero.

Second, when you do hook it up write, the content will end up writing on top of each other. You can not use load() and expect it to work in a loop.

Here is the basic idea:

```
(function () {
    var pageCounter = 1;
    var tableRowsTotal = 0;
    max pageMax=10;
    function loadPage() {
         $.get('/folder/?p='+pageCounter, function(data){
             var table = $(data).filter(".standart-view");
             //or
             //var table = $(data).find(".standart-view");
             var rows = table.find("tbody tr");
             var rowCount = rows.length;
             console.log(pageCounter, rowCount);
             tableRowsTotal += rowCount;
             pageCounter++;
             if(pageCounter<pageMax) {
                 loadPage();
             } else {
                   console.log("done");
             }
        });
    }
    loadPage();
}());
```